# How can I kill whatever process is using port 8080 so that I can vagrant up?

Tags: macos, networking, vagrant

On MacOSX, I'm using Packer to build a Vagrant box so I need to continually bring it up and tear it down. I'm attempting to 'vagrant up', and receive the standard error because the port is in use:

"Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they would collide with some other application that is already listening on these ports. The forwarded port to 8080 is already in use on the host machine."

The solution seems simple enough: I just need to identify the process that is holding port 8080 open and kill that process, right?. It's not that easy.

---

If I run the command:

```
nmap localhost -p 8080
```

I receive the following output:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

---

If I run the following command:

```
top -o prt
```

The highest port in use in 1360

---

If I run the following command:

```
 netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
```

I receive:

```
netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
```

---

If I run the following command:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

I receive no output

---

If I restart my computer, the port is now available and I can now 'vagrant up'.

How can I kill whatever process is using port 8080 so that I can vagrant up without restarting my computer?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

This might help

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8080
```

The PID is the second field in the output.

Or try:

```
lsof -i -P
```

Comment: Do you happen to have an HP LaserJet printer? http://blog.hgomez.net/blog/2010/09/25/how-to-fix-hp-laserjet-1102w-printeragent-using-port-8080-on-mac/

Comment: Thanks Mark! For whatever reason, after restarting my computer, the lsof commands were outputting nothing, and now they are. Now, all 3 of the of the lsof commands are working and I can identify the process id and kill it with: sudo kill -9 000 ... Where 000 is the process id. The name of the process is "VBoxHeadless". If I get more information on why it was not working previously I will report back. FYI: I have no printer attached.

Comment: Try `sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8080` to pick up processes owned by root.

Answer (score 143):

### Fast and quick solution:

`lsof -n -i4TCP:8080`

`PID` is the second field. Then, kill that process:

`kill -9 PID`

### Less fast but permanent solution

1. Go to `/usr/local/bin/`   (Can use command+shift+g in finder)
2. Make a file named `stop`. Paste the below code in it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
touch temp.text
lsof -n -i4TCP:$1 | awk '{print $2}' > temp.text
pidToStop=`(sed '2q;d' temp.text)`
> temp.text
if [[ -n $pidToStop ]]
then
kill -9 $pidToStop
echo "Congrates!! $1 is stopped."
else
echo "Sorry nothing running on above port"
fi
rm temp.text
```

3. Save this file.
4. Make the file executable `chmod 755 stop`
5. Now, go to terminal and write `stop 8888` (or any port)

Comment: I tried the permanent solution but got 'Permission denied' when attempting to run the script. Solved by first running `chmod 755 stop`.

Answer (score 40):

In case above-accepted answer did not work, try below solution. 
You can use it for port 8080 or for any other ports.

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Replace 3000 with whichever port you want. Run below command to kill that process.

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

PID is process ID you want to kill.

**Below is the output of commands on mac Terminal.**

[image: Command output]

Comment: i'd try regular kill (not -9) first. The -9 option could result in the socket not being closed properly. The process may be killed but another listener will forked in its place.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following command:

`lsof -n -i4TCP:8080 | awk '{print$2}' | tail -1 | xargs kill -9`

The process id of port 8080 will be picked and killed forcefully using `kill -9`.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to kill processes on different ports so I created a bash script:

```
killPort() {
  PID=$(echo $(lsof -n -i4TCP:$1) | awk 'NR==1{print $11}')
  kill -9 $PID
}
```

Just add that to your .bashrc and run it like this:

```
killPort 8080
```

You can pass whatever port number you wish

Answer (score 6):

To script this:

```
pid=$(lsof -ti tcp:8080)
if [[ $pid ]]; then
  kill -9 $pid
fi
```

The `-t` argument makes the output of lsof "terse" which means that it only returns the PID.

Comment: you may make it function too that takes $port

Comment: Finally a solution that gets the PID directly. Thanks man, should be the correct answer to this thread

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo lsof -i:8080
```

By running the above command you can see what are all the jobs running.

```
kill -9 <PID Number>
```

Enter the PID (process identification number), so this will terminate/kill the instance.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to run this command

```
sudo lsof -i :80 # checks port 8080
```

Then i got

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
acwebseca 312 root   36u  IPv4 0x34ae935da20560c1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.3:50585->104.25.53.12:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

show which service is using the PID

```
ps -ef 312
```

Then I got this

```
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0   312    58   0  9:32PM ??         0:02.70 /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/acwebsecagent -console
```

To uninstall cisco web security agent run

```
sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh
```

credits to: http://tobyaw.livejournal.com/315396.html

Answer (score 3):

It can be Cisco AnyConnect. 
Check if /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist  exists. Then unload it with launchctl and delete from /Library/LaunchDaemons

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Activity Monitor to identify and quit the process using the port.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: On MacOSX: Activity Monitor > Network > sort by PID > find your blocked port (eg 8080, 5000 etc) > click top left 'X' > confirm you want to quit the process. May be a good idea to edit your run/build configuration to ensure only single server instances can be created, ie your used ports are freed on teardown.

Answer (score 1):

Run: `nmap -p 8080 localhost` (Install nmap with MacPorts or Homebrew if you don't have it on your system yet)

> Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
>
> Host is up (0.00034s latency).
>
> Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
>
> PORT     STATE SERVICE
>
> 8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Run: `ps -ef | grep http-proxy`

> UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
>
> 640 99335 88310   0  12:26pm ttys002    0:00.01 grep http-proxy"

Run: `ps -ef 640` (replace 501 with your UID)

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis.animationperfd.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis.animationperfd

Port 8080 on mac osx is used by something [installed with XCode SDK](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/tree/master/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks)

Answer (score 1):

try netstat

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000
```

if your netstat doesn't support -p , use lsof

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:3000
```

For Centos 7 use

```
netstat -vanp --tcp | grep 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

After referring to the solution of @voutasaurus. I wrote this utility to simplify the process of killing all the processes that are running on the port.

```
killProcessesUsing3000 () {
  pid=$(lsof -ti :3000)  # The -t argument makes the output of lsof "terse" (Brief) which means that it only returns the PID.
  # PID contains process processes that run on the 3000 port. In new lines if they are multiples
  for num ($=pid) {
    echo $num
    kill -9 $num
  }
}

#Alias
alias kill3000="killProcessesUsing3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

Open your mac terminal

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

Explanation:

`lsof -t` returns the PID and passes that to kill.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the above and they didn't work for me.

After many hours, I found this one liner:

```sh
# kill 8080
alias nuke88="lsof -i tcp:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill"

# kill 3000
alias nuke3k="lsof -i tcp:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill"
```