# How to determine what process is listening on OSX

Tags: macos, apache, laravel, laravel-valet

Trying to help configure Laravel Valet on a Mac running El Capitan, and the user had installed `MAMP` previously. `MAMP` is disabled but anytime we load a valet address (`mysite.dev`) we get a standard Apache `404` page.

Is there a way to determine what process is listening on port 80 and conflicting with Valet so I can disable it?

Comment: You can hopefully adapt this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388281/2836621

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN
```

Or some such.

Comment: Omitting `:80` will show all processes that are listening.