# OS High Sierra - can't figure out what is listening on port 80

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

When i do a simple http://localhost i get the standard apache "It Works!"

However when I do a search for running services httpd is nowhere to be found.

When I try to manually shut of httpd through the console? The respoonse is "the httpd service is not running"

This is more annoying than anything because I have to run MAMP on a different port as well as my ZF app.

I've done extensive research online trying to figure out why httpd appears to be running transparently but can't seem to find a consistent answer. Apparently I'm not the only one to have a mysterious service on High Sierra hogging up port 80.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388281/2836621

Answer (score 1):

MacOS is delivered with a functional Apache server. It is managed by launchd.

```
sudo launchctl list | grep http
```

should show `org.apache.httpd` service. If you are able to see "It works!" that means that a server is running. It is very strange that you can't see any "httpd" process.

```
ps -eax | grep httpd
```

must show you at least one httpd process. Even `Activity Monitor.app` will.

You will find log files of the server into `/var/log/apache2` and the pid file path is `/var/run/httpd.pid`. All this may helps you to find what happens...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.  For anyone interested it is "launchd" and can be resolved by doing

"sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist"