# Find out what is running on my port 80 on a Mac OSX

Tags: macos, http, docker

I'm trying to start a `hello-world` container app that I just build using nodejs on my Mac OS X.

**docker run -p 80:80 --name web -d node-hello**

```
343503e8a29ac207c821caa7990373580dd6a1951e1e4936bbf9c71b0eff2213
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint web (e6035cf3ae4df37f1a96a5a7ed321e6a0ae7ad484c05aae8d7b67f3d86fa3a76): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

## Debug Steps

I went to the address

[image]

I ran this

**lsof -i ":80"**

and got

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    956 bheng  225u  IPv6 0x5bed1c283af57fa7      0t0  TCP [2607:f518:15e:9540:3105:c54f:bd3c:14ed]:63120->yul02s04-in-x10.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)


(netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 80) 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.4380         *.*                    LISTEN                                                                
tcp46      0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

How do I find out what is **exactly** running on my port 80 right now ?

Comment: Is port 80 in listen (`netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 80`).  If yes, switch to an administrator account and do `lsof | grep LISTEN`, it will give you the PID.

Comment: Do you need to use port 80?

Comment: @cricket_007 : I left one result on my post, but here is another one base on Nic3500's comment : https://i.imgur.com/RlyIZtk.png

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388281/2836621

Answer (score 14):

Prefix lsof with sudo to see process ids that you don’t own.

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

Comment: I did that I see nothing useful that might have cause the 403.

Comment: If somebody will get into the trouble, use this https://superuser.com/questions/597398/no-idea-what-is-listening-on-port-80-in-os-x