# How to quit webpack running after restart?

Tags: node.js, macos, webpack, gatsby

That one is weird. I used Visual Studio Code to build a site with Gatsby.js. At some point I restarted my mac (Catalina) and with that, the VS Code as well.

But now, even after many reboots and without VS Code running at all, I have Gatsby's development server constantly running at http://localhost:9000. Can't find anything in Task Manager that resembles Node or Gatsby or Webpack.

How to quit that rogue web server?

Comment: Hey @Sven tryout this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388281/13058340

Comment: It might be because of cache, clear the cache and see if it still works.

Comment: Do you use Docker?

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill all node listening ports. Just use: `killall -9 node`. It works for any node port, not just the `9000`.

Another guess is to run `ps aux | grep webpack` to find the webpack running port and `kill $(ps aux | grep 'webpack' | awk '{print $2}')` to kill it.

Source: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/issues/240#issuecomment-317131545

Comment: Did that. Got "No matching processes belonging to you were found". But I can still reload my site running localhost…

Comment: Updated answer with another guess @Sven .

Comment: Hmm, "ps aux | grep webpack" gives me something (sven             21160   0.0  0.0  4268300    696 s007  S+    4:16PM   0:00.00 grep webpack). 

But "kill $(ps aux | grep 'webpack' | awk '{print $2}') " does not kill it. Instead, it tells me there is no such process (kill 21258 failed: no such process)

Comment: What about `killall -KILL node` ?

Comment: "killall -KILL node" gets me "No matching processes belonging to you were found". Aha, maybe some other user has this server running?

Comment: And yet using "sudo killall -KILL node" gives me "No matching processes were found"

Trying to kill process by ID gives me the same result…